# Find the area of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by an implicit relation.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, area

Let x, y, z be real numbers and let 
$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&x&x^{2} \\ 1&y&y^{2} \\ 1&z&z^{2}
\end{bmatrix} 
$

Let S be the subset of $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ given by $S = \{ (x,y,x) \in \mathbf{R}^{3} \: |\: x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} \leq 1 $, and det A=0$ \}$. Find the area of S.

I'm assuming I need to use the surface area formula
$A(S) = \iint_D \sqrt{1+ (\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^{2} + (\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})^{2}}\,dx \,dy$.

Expanding out the determinant directly becomes messy, so I think that I may be missing something.  Does the guaranteed linear dependence of the vectors help me somehow?  Also I know I do not have to solve for z explicitly to find the partial derivatives ($\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} $ and $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$) but solving for the partial derivatives with implicit differentiation yields a solution in terms of z (as well as x and y). Finally, I am at a loss in determining the domain that I integrate over.

Also this is my first time posting to stackexchange and first time using latex, so I apologize for any formatting issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The matrix is a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). So: $$\begin{vmatrix}
1&x&x^{2} \\ 1&y&y^{2} \\ 1&z&z^{2}
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 1& 1 & 1 \\ x & y & z \\ x
^2 & y^2 & z^2\end{vmatrix} = (y-x)(z-x)(z-y).$$

Now analyzing $\det A = 0$ is easy. Look at the intersection of the sphere with the planes $x = y$, $z = x$ and $y = z$. You actually don't need to suffer so much using integrals..